# Angular js ng-repeat and ng-show not working on refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jhipster

Hello I have the following problem: I have created a web app with angular js and spring. It is a platform where you can post some messages. Therefore on the angular controller I have written the following code.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="message in messages">
                <div class="col-md-4 mb" style="margin-left: 40px;">
                    <div class="darkblue-panel pn">
                        <div class="darkblue-header">
                            <h5>{{messages.message}}</h5>
                        </div>
                        {{messages.creator}} {{messages.date | date:'dd.MM.yy'}}
                        <br/>
                        <div ng-show="'{{messages.creator}}'=='{{settingsAccount.login}}'">
                            <button type="submit"
                                    ng-click="update(messages.id)"
                                    class="btn btn-default">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit
                            </button>
                            <button type="submit"
                                    ng-click="delete(messages.id)"
                                    class="btn btn-danger">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span> Delete
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Notice the ng-show. This line is responsible that the buttons to edit and delete the message are only shown to the creator of a message.

So far everything works perfectly fine. The message is displayed with the buttons. The problem comes when I refresh the page. Then the Message is shown but the buttons to edit and delete disapeared.

The values (messages.creator and settingsAccount.login) are still the same but I think that the ng-show is not checking after a refresh. When I paste a new message the ng-show condition is checked and I am able to edit the message I pasted before, as well as the message I just pasted.

How can I solve this problem? Why is the ng-shown condition not checked after a page refresh? Is the ng-repeat executed after a refresh?

Comment: Could be how you are fetching the messages. Try using a promise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am already using $promise. Is there another way to solve the problem?

Comment: I found out that after a refresh the settingsAccount.login is undefined and therefore the check fails. Why is it undefined? Is it because it is cached?

Comment: I assume `settingsAccount` is the service which the user crendentials, status and etc. is stored. How is the information stored? Cookies, localstorage, session?

Comment: Yes exactly. After the login I store it in a Session.

Comment: I had the same issue while developing a site recently. The session is removed after a manual refresh, not sure why. You should look into this: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage Really easy to set up and it has cookie fallback.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's related, but in jhipster's default setup the object holding the information of the currently logged in user is `account`, `settingsAccount` is only used in the settings page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a solution. After a refresh i loose the values from the Session. To solve this problem I am using now the localStorage or Cookies which I initialize at the beginning.